# ios unity game crashes at startup because of advertisement.initializeAds() How do I fix it?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-development

my unity ios game I've made has this new bug. It hasn't occured before but it started faintly appearing back 3 months ago. Keep in mind I haven't made a update in those 3 months and those faint errors happening rarely started to increase. And now, it occurs every time on newer devices.
I've updated the ads package, and updated the skadnetwork ids.

here's the script for it:
`
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

```
public class AdsInitializer : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsInitializationListener,            IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{
[SerializeField] string _androidGameId;
[SerializeField] string _iOSGameId;
string _gameId;
[SerializeField] bool _testMode = false;


private void Awake()
{
    //currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

    
    //Advertisement.Initialize(_iOSGameId, true); 
    
    if (Advertisement.isInitialized)
    {
        Debug.Log("Advertisement is Initialized");
        //LoadRewardedAd();
    }
    else
    {
        InitializeAds();
    }
}

public void InitializeAds()
{
    _gameId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) ? _iOSGameId :                                        _androidGameId;
    Advertisement.Initialize(_iOSGameId, _testMode, this);
    }
```

..... the rest of the code......
`

I've tried updating the package to latest. I included the skadnetwork ids, and that's about it.
this error just sort of built up in the background and reached a limit. it only happens on newer devices like ios15-17 (possibly 14)
the reason could be ios 14 support package, but i've taken care of that.
I'll look into it but if there's an issue with my ads script.
please let me know.

thank you so much for your time and patience!

Comment: put some protection around it?

Comment: protection? care to elaborate

Comment: try/except depending on what issue you actually have, not waiting on it also may help if its causing things to time out as its not ending in a reasonable time.

Comment: I'll see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code:
https://docs.unity.com/ads/en-us/manual/InitializingTheUnitySDK

```
void Awake ()
{
    InitializeAds();
}

public void InitializeAds()
{
#if UNITY_IOS
        _gameId = _iOSGameId;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        _gameId = _androidGameId;
#elif UNITY_EDITOR
        _gameId = _androidGameId; //Only for testing the functionality in the Editor
#endif
    if (!Advertisement.isInitialized && Advertisement.isSupported)
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize(_gameId, _testMode, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it, it was the ads